# i want to make conditional trigger in sql server......

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, triggers

i have a table named test and another table named trigg..... what i want is.... whenever data having 'name' as 'rakesh' is being inserted to test...it should fire a trigger to insert the age in the 'trigg' table....

i tried by my self.... chk it...

```
create trigger trigger1 
on test
after insert
as
if((select name from test) like 'rakesh')
begin 
insert into trigg(age)
select name from test
end
```

but it didnt worked..
whenever  i am inserting in test ..getting this error :

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

help me out....

Answer (score 1):

- You are selecting from **test** when you should be selecting from **INSERTED**. You want your statements to take effect based on what is being inserted, not based on what the table may contain.
- Even after that is changed, a trigger fires once per statement, not once per row. If an insert affects multiple rows, then the **INSERTED** pseudotable will contain multiple rows, and the subselect would therefore fail.

Suggested revision:

```
create trigger trigger1 
on test
after insert
as
if EXISTS (select * from INSERTED where name like 'rakesh')
begin 
    insert into trigg(age)
    select name from INSERTED 
    where name like 'rakesh'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your trigger, I am guessing you made the incorrect assumtion that only one record at a time is processed in a trigger and you therefore tried to set some scalear variable to the value of a field in inserted or deleted like this:

```
set @test = (select id from inserted)
```

You have to write the trigger with the assumption that there will be muilitple records porcessed at aone time. This is set-theory not row-by row processing.

The other possibility is that you have some subquery in the action query you are using and that indeed it returns multiple records.

Another possibility is that the trigg table has a poorly written query on it and that is what is causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON test AFTER insert AS

INSERT INTO trigg (age)
SELECT name FROM INSERTED
WHERE name like 'rakesh'
```

I'm guessing at your table structure based on the code you supplied, but this should be closer to what you need.